# QML: Donut pie graph without QtChart module

Tags: qt, qml, pie-chart, qtcharts

I have a Qt-QML application where I have a donut pie graph.

Now I am using a ChartView with a PieSeries (full of PieSlice items)

I need to change my QML class to avoid using QtChart module.

Which would be the best idea?

Comment: What is the reason not to use QtCharts?

Comment: can you provide code or example output ?

Comment: @folibis I just received this requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is totally unclear what are your objections against QtCharts @Diego, there are plenty of options. Some of options:

- Draw whatever you want on [`Canvas2d`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html) -- in this case you need to implement all charts painting.
- Use [Charts.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) -- Simple yet flexible JavaScript charting for designers & developers in your project (integrate via the same `Canvas2d`). There are few of implementation that brings Charts.js into QML, e.g.:

  - https://github.com/MichaelVoelkel/ChartJs2QML
  - https://github.com/qyvlik/Chart.qml

Comment: I just received this requirement... Thanks, this will be really useful!!